# Event Online Registration text cannot show 'by' [WP5.3, CIVICRM 5.21.2]

Tags: civievent

I have a CIVICRM site that we recently turned on the Event module which we noticed a strange bug.  For some reason, when we write the word 'by' in the Event Online Registration Introductory text, it will be omitted at the Live Link where we view the Event registration page.  the word 'by' is absent in the html source.  even stranger, if i type in 'BY' (cap), it will appear at the event registration page ok.

so if we typed in "Register by tommorrow", live link shows "Register tommorrow""
if we typed in "Register BY tommorrow", live link shows the same text.

however, this doesn't happen when we view the Test-Drive page, 'by' is displayed as expected.

thanks.

Comment: That's a new one. Check Administer - Customize - Word Replacements? But that wouldn't explain the test-drive, but it's one thing to check.

Comment: that's a good tip to look at Word Replacements, but sadly nothing was set up to be replaced.